# Streaming wowza to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, live-streaming, wowza

I'm streaming a live event via Wowza. I can see the downstream via rtmp, and in vlc with the *playlist.m3u8* url, as stated in the "iOS and Mac OS X" example.
However this url doesn't work on the iPhone: I get a very informative "*video could not played*" message.
So beside the **<LiveStreamPacketizers>** part of the Application.xml configuration, is there something special to enable to make it work on iPhones?

TIA

greg

Comment: Are you able to play other http live streaming url with your code ?

Comment: does your url works with quick time player ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't try on a Mac, and it was not really a "code", just a URL given to mobile safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: you have to send "baseline 3.0" h264 to cover old iPhones.